# RSA decrypting a Web.config section

Tags: asp.net, powershell, web-config

I'm trying to decrypt a Web.config section that was encrypted with RSA from an external Powershell script. The section goes:

```
<connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider">
    <EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
      <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
      <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
          <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
          <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <KeyName>Rsa Key</KeyName>
          </KeyInfo>
          <CipherData>
            <CipherValue>.......</CipherValue>
          </CipherData>
        </EncryptedKey>
      </KeyInfo>
      <CipherData>
        <CipherValue>.......</CipherValue>
      </CipherData>
    </EncryptedData>
</connectionStrings>
```

The code goes:

```
[xml]$x = Get-Content "$Path\Web.config"
$Prov = New-Object System.Configuration.RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider
$Prov.Decrypt($x.configuration.connectionStrings.EncryptedData)
```

It's executed via remote Powershell on the server where the config is. The account is an admin, so local machine keys should be available. And I'm getting an error:

```
Value cannot be null. Parameter name: keyName
```

An identical, modulo provider name, fragment works for DPAPI encrypted sections. The key name is right there in the section. What am I missing here?

Update: when the Web code does it, it calls `Initialize()` on the provider first. I've mimicked the parameters on that Initialize call. They come from machine. config.

```
$nv = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection
$nv.Add("description", "Uses RsaCryptoServiceProvider to encrypt and decrypt")
$nv.Add("keyContainerName", "NetFrameworkConfigurationKey")
$nv.Add("cspProviderName", "")
$nv.Add("useMachineContainer", "true")
$nv.Add("useOAEP", "false")
$Prov.Initialize("RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider", $nv)
```

Now I'm getting a different error: "Bad data".

Update 2: tried siccing aspnet_regiis on that file, got the same "Bad data" error. But the site itself seems up and running and database aware. Maybe the connectionString section **is** damaged after all, and the site takes it elsewhere.

Comment: try doing it from System.Web.Configuration liabrary if you want i can provide a snippet?

Answer (score 0):

I"m not sure about doing it via Powershell but here's what I do manually via code-behind on a web page. There might be a clue in here. I can delete this answer if it doesn't help.

```
protected void btnEncryptConnStrings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Open web.config file as a configuration object to get information.
    Configuration objConfigFile = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(Request.ApplicationPath);

    // Work with the <connectionStrings> section.
    ConfigurationSection connectionStrings = objConfigFile.GetSection("connectionStrings");

    if(connectionStrings != null)
    {
        // Only encrypt the section if it is not already protected.
        if(!connectionStrings.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
        {
            // Encrypt the <connectionStrings> section using the
            // DataProtectionConfigurationProvider provider (see notes at top of file).
            connectionStrings.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider"); // alt: DataProtectionConfigurationProvider

            objConfigFile.Save();

            // other stuff.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code relies on being inside an ASP.NET application. `OpenWebConfiguration()` doesn't accept an absolute path to Web.config, it takes a virtual one and tries to resolve it against the current site. My script runs standalone.